# matlab structures finding duplicates in one field to search through another field

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a large structure with many fields but I need to find the index of the min magnitude at each time interval.

```
Structure(:).Time = [ 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  11, 11, 21, 21, 21, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, ...]
Structure(:).Mag = [ 11, 16, 9, 4, 6, 111, 10,  8, 15,  3,  0, 95, 52, 16,  7, ...]
```

So the solution should be:

```
Solutionindex = [ 4, 7, 10, 11, ...]
```

To correspond with time = 1, Mag = 4; time = 11, Mag = 10; time = 21, Mag = 3; time = 31, Mag = 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) (and its trusty sidekick [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html))!

```
% Sample data:
Structure = struct('Time', { 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  11, 11, 21, 21, 21, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31}, ...
                   'Mag', {11, 16, 9, 4, 6, 111, 10,  8, 15,  3,  0, 95, 52, 16,  7});

[timeVals, ~, index] = unique([Structure(:).Time]);  % Find an index for unique times
nTimes = cumsum(accumarray(index, 1));  % Count the number of each unique time
Solutionindex = accumarray(index, [Structure(:).Mag].', [], @(x) find(x == min(x), 1)) + ...
                [0; nTimes(1:(end-1))];
```

And the result:

```
Solutionindex =

     4
     7
    10
    11
```

Answer (score 0):

With `unique`, you can get the different time intervals, then some logic and `find`. In `find` the second argument is number of indices to return. This is set to 1 to return the first index. If the last index is wanted, add `, 'last'` behind the `1`.

```
Time = [ 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  11, 11, 21, 21, 21, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31];
Mag = [ 11, 16, 9, 4, 6, 111, 10,  8, 15,  3,  0, 95, 52, 16,  7];

[uniques,idx] = unique(Time);
Solutionindex = zeros(1,length(uniques));
for ii=1:length(uniques)
    Solutionindex(ii) = find(Mag(Time==uniques(ii)) == min(Mag(Time==uniques(ii))),1)+idx(ii)-1;
end
```

Result:

```
Solutionindex =

     4     7    10    11
```

Comment: I've been trying to use unique but due to the struct (i think) I've been getting "Too many input arguments." errors

Comment: I'm not sure why but I got it working with uniques = unique([Structure(:).Time]');

Comment: That's because I didn't define a struct as you did.